# F# Discriminated Unions and Printing

Tags: f#

I am trying to solve the problem below, but have difficulties figuring out how to print it in the desired format, with parenthesis and numbers / operators.

[image]

[image]

I have the code below to create expressions, but printing %A using match pattern does not work. I can access values but cannot print them in the desired format. Anyone has suggestions?

```
let one = Const(1)
let two = Const(2)
let three = Const(3)
let Bin1 = BinOpr(one, "+", two)
let Bin2 = BinOpr(Bin1, "*", three)
```

Comment: I think this would be instructive to figure out on your own.  As a hint, note it's not asking you to print, but rather create a function that creates a string.  You'll have to `match` on the input of that function to create the desired output.  i.e. `let toString expr = match expr with | Const i -> `...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to implement `toString` by pattern matching on `expr` and output the appropriate string for `Const` and `BinOpr`:

- For `Const`, you just need to convert your `int` to a string.
- For `BinOpr`, you have to build a string of the form `(<expr> <op> <expr>)`.

Try to implement the function yourself, it's not that difficult but in the case you get stuck, I provide the solution below.

---

### Solution

```
let rec toString expr =
  match expr with
  | Const x -> string x
  | BinOpr (e1, op, e2) -> sprintf "(%s %s %s)" (toString e1) op (toString e2)
```